# Regex to certain special characters

Tags: regex

Currently i have this following regex which i use to validate the name of a company/industry and its working fine

```
  /(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{5,25}$)^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/
```

The above regex doesnt supports for special characters like & - . _ which are valid in my case

I came up with this but it wasnt working as expected.

```
 /(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-\&\_\.]{5,25}$)^[a-zA-Z0-9\&\_\.]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9\&\_\.]+)*$/
```

Can someone point it out where my above regex goes wrong. Also a short explaination of the above regex wud be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: The real question is whether there even *is* such a thing as a a regex that can validate company names. Have you looked at the crazy names some companies use? Have you thought about foreign countries with different alphabets? Does it even make sense to use a regex here? What effect should it have?

Comment: this is not a jQuery question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you have to escape `&` with `\&`, same way `_` also

```
/(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-&_\.]{5,25}$)^[a-zA-Z0-9&_\.]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9&_\.]+)*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you don't actually have to put backslash with every special character unless the special character is the backslash itself or the character `-`. So your regular expression would be

```
/(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-&_.]{5,25}$)^[a-zA-Z0-9&_.]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9&_.]+)*$/
```